# Is there any XML-Tag associations or mapping for updraging Tomcat's web.xml file to GlassFish4's glassfish-web.xml configuration file?

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml, tomcat8, spring-tool-suite, glassfish-4.1

glassfish-web.xml file was by default included when i checked "GlassFish Web Extension" checkbox in Project Facets of the web application properties.

Is there any xml-tag association or mapping between GlassFish and Tomcat web configuration files for upgrading from Tomcat to GlassFish Server?

Apart from this issue, In Spring Tool Suite, both Tomcat and GlassFish Server were added and then tried to execute the web application on Tomcat Server, by default GlassFish is taking over it and starting.

When I am trying to start Tomcat Server this is the error message it is displaying:

[image]

Comment: Sole Tomcat Server startup issue is solved: GlassFish4 Server removed from Servers tab in STS, then tried to start Tomcat Server again, but couldnot achieve to start Tomcat Server. A fresh installation of Tomcat Server on computer was done and added to STS, then it started working. While retaining both the servers in STS and running project in Tomcat Server yet to be checked. But xml-tag mapping from web.xml to glassfish-web.xml web consiguration file not yet solved.

Comment: Obviously it is clear from the error message that, the Server project/folder is closed in project explorer and need to be open by right click and select open project. May be this would have helped.